# How to convert CSV file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a file, each line of which is a list of comma separated values. For example,

```
1, a, b, c, d, e
2, x, y, z
```

Now I would like to convert it in `bash` as follows:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
1 e
2 x
2 y
2 z
```

How to do it with a `shell (bash)` script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,$i}' temp
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1, a, b, c, d, e
2, x, y, z
> awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,$i}' temp
1  a
1  b
1  c
1  d
1  e
2  x
2  y
2  z
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the line into tokens and put them in an array. The first element of the array will be having the number, in your case it is 1 or 2 and so on. Something like this may be :

```
while read line
do
    arrIN=(${line//,/ })

## make a loop and echo them
## arrIN[0] will have the initial number

done < $file

# $file is the input file you are reading
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need a shell script, but does it need to be bash ? e.g. I would normally use a higher-level scripting language and a CSV library. e.g. `Perl` and [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

Comment: I don't think any CSV library (not even for non-scripting languages, like Java) could solve this use-case out of the box, as this is a weird way of processing CSV data -- and that data is not even real CSV. As a side note, from your answer one could understand that Perl is a sort of "shell script", which is not the case.

Comment: Downvoted why ? Suggesting a higher-level scripting language and CSV-oriented lib doesn't seem unreasonable here

Comment: And how is the above "not even real CSV" ?

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer; I don't think it's bad, although I don't find it particularly useful.

Comment: As for the "real CSV" question, although there's no true standard for CSV, RFC-4180 for the `text/csv` mime type states that "each line should contain the same number of fields throughout the file" (empty fields should be listed explicitely like: `a,b,,,`); some libraries are likely to impose this precondition when parsing CSV input.

Comment: Moreover, according to that RFC, spaces should *not* be ignored, as seems to be the case here.

Comment: I don't think anyone is suggesting that CSV example above is RFC compliant

Comment: Agreed. The point however is that a CSV library (as you suggested) is likely to fail parsing such an input and custom logic is required anyway.